# how do I find the smallest number in a text file? (Java)

Tags: java, numbers

I have written code for a program meant to have the user input a text file and an output file, then the program must read each line in the input file to find the smallest number. The output is supposed to have the smallest number followed by "<== smallest number". When I run it the smallest number ends up being the last number in the text file every time

This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindSmallest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Your input file: ");
    String inputFileName = console.next();
    System.out.print("Your output file: ");
    String outputFileName = console.next();


    File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);

    double smallNum = in.nextDouble();

    while(in.hasNextDouble()){

        double number = in.nextDouble();
        if (number < smallNum); {
            smallNum = number;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(smallNum);
    //out.printf("%8.2f <== smallest number", smallNum);
   in.close(); 
   out.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you print out each time you do an assignment?  Maybe the last number really is the smallest.

Comment: I have the list of numbers and the smallest number is 1, there must me and error in my code that is reading through the file and then picking the last number and assigning it to smallNum.

Comment: the semicolon after if statement will end up the if scope, so 'smallNum = number' would execute every time in the while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, remove the ';' right after the `if (number < smallNum)`. The `;` after the `if` causes the `smallNum = number;' instruction to run irrespective of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use import java.io.*; instead of importing specific libraries to shorten your code. "*" calls up all the libraries in the specified import.

Comment: Your response does not answer the question. Maybe you could focus on the question what the author should change in his code to find the smallest number in a file.